# How pinch zoom in/out events are detected in google map?

Tags: android, events, user-interface, canvas, android-widget

I have a requirement in which I have to detect pinch zoom in/out event, so that when user zoom in my canvas will redraw itself to more bigger size and with more content and when user zoom out the canvas will again redraw itself to smaller size and with less content on canvas.

Is there any way to do this? Any nudge would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps Api v2 for Android?

Comment: No, I am not using google map, but want to detect similar events(pinch in/out zoom) in my android app, so that I can attach these events to listeners.

Comment: I understand, my bad. Something like this perhaps ? http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/